# Como faço para executar um comando uma vez a cada hora em python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quero executar um codigo/linha de codigos uma vez a cada hora ao rodar o programa em python, como faço ser executado a cada hora?

Comment: Qual o sistema operacional? Você provavelmente teria que agendar a execução de um script, veja essa pergunta no SOen: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2725754/8133067

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu recomendo você dar uma olhada na biblioteca **schedule**

```
import schedule
import time

def f():
    print("Hello World")

schedule.every().hour.do(f)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Um norte para vc usar no seu codigo para executar a cada hora.

```
import time
while True:
    print("passou 1 hora executa esse comando")
    time.sleep(3600) #A cada hora ele executa o print
```